# Is this "Chat with an expert" a new items on SE sites?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I have noticed just today that there is a banner that will pop up now and again when I am on SU.

[image: Chat].

Is this something new?

Comment: Today's April 1 remember ;p

Comment: Now and again? Again, and again, and again, and again, and again, and bloody again, and again and again, and again, and again.  What is this?  the rebirth of clippy?

Comment: Oops, I seriously believed "the expert" want to help me with IPv6. Remembered about the April Fool only here.

Comment: Just saying, I tried this out, and it was extremely annoying

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Yes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174411/139837)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A suggestion for this "feature", inspired by the StackOverflowSort (XKCD).

Grab some keywords from the user's question, search on SO (or whatever site context), take the top question with an accepted answer, and return the first/last/random sentence from the answer.

Though this might have the tragic byproduct of the feature actually being...  useful.  *gasp*

Comment: This probably makes for a better tech-support then the actual support of many big companies.

Answer (score 2):

It's an April Fools' joke.  The "expert" is simply a basic AI that repeats a select set of words you write, inserting them into a set of possible responses in order to form a reasonably coherent (grammatically speaking) statement.

See this Meta Stack Overflow question: [What is "chat with an expert"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert)